# Como recuperar um arquivo excluído pelo comando "rm"?

Tags: shell, shell-script

Excluí um arquivo por acidente por meio do comando `rm`.

Existe alguma forma de recuperá-lo?

Comment: Boa tarde Rodrigo, você quer desenvolver um software para recuperar? Caso contrário, você só conseguirá fazer isto com softwares específicos para recuperação, até aonde sei.

Comment: Imaginei que iriam querer fechar a pergunta. Não fui eu :)

Comment: Poxa, tem a ver com programação sim. :)

Comment: Então Rodrigo não é só a questão de programação, mas como esta na pergunta atual, não evidencia nada de programação, apenas se existe meio de recuperar, que no caso até o momento só se trata do `rm`. Se a pergunta for melhor elaborada provavelmente não será fechada, pois da maneira que esta ela da brechas para respostas que nada tem haver com programação, entende? Espero que leve como uma critica construtiva :)

Comment: É verdade, faz sentido. :) Vou melhorá-la para evitar esse tipo de situação.

Answer (score 0):

Há possibilidades, porém poderia tornar o seu sistema inconsistente (caso o aplicativo ainda esteja sendo executado), sugiro que verifique o administrador do servidor se possui algum backup. Além disso também sugiro que utilize o sistema de "lixeira" para que não ocorra novamente no futuro.

#move o lixo para lixeira:

```
  alias deletar 'mv\!* ~/.lixeira'
```

#exclusão irreversível:

```
  alias excluirLixeira 'rm -rf ~/.lixeira/ ;mkdir ~/.lixeira'
```

#verifica se a lixeira existe:

```
  if ( ! -d ~/.lixeira ) mkdir ~/.lixeira
```